# Use checkbox for a particular condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button that I am executing/clicking and I want this 3 lines to be a condition if I tick a checkbox else this should not be performed. Please help. Thank you in advance!

```
Worksheets("Ticket Based").Select
Range("A1:G2, Table_0").Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: Do you know how to refer to the checkbox? Do you know what kind of checkbox (form-controller/ Active-X)?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the state of your checkbox and execute code based on it's state like this

```
If myCheckbox = True Then
    'do something when box is ticked
Else
    'do something else
End If
```

Best Regards,

Sythr

Comment: Instead of If myCheckbox = True Then, I used:

If Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = True Then
and it worked. Thanks everyone

Comment: Oh yes, I was looking at some code of mine and forgot that I worked on a UserForm, for ActiveX / OLEObjects you sure have to address it that way :)